# Why is it that if I take the limit as x approaches a of $\lim_{x\to a}(c)=c $ & $\lim_{x\to a}(x)=a$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Why is it that if I take the limit as x approaches a of $\lim_{x\to a}(c)=c $ & $\lim_{x\to a}(x)=a$?

what I don't understand is that a in the first limit isn't on the right of the equal sign which is odd because it is for the other limit.

Why is this?

Comment: You're taking the limit as $k$ goes to $a$. Did you mean this?

Comment: In the first one, the function is $f(x)=c$ which means no matter what value of x I put into it I will always get c out as an answer (it's a horizontal line) so as I move along the x axis towards the point a, the value remains at c right up until I get exactly to a in this case. The second is the function $f(x)=x$, can you see what happens as I choose different values of x?

Comment: These results are immediate consequences of the definition of limit.